# Count specific values of PHP Array that has no column assignments

Tags: php, count, array-key-exists, array-sum

I need to display a count of the no of car makes.

```
$array = array(
                array(1,'Benz'),
                array(3,'Toyota'), 
                array(4,'Mazda'),
                [2,'VW'],
                [5,'Mazda']
            );


$count = array_count_values(array_column($array, <what do I use here?>;

print_r($count)
```

Comment: What should be the expected output and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use number (0,1,2, etc) as second argument:

```
$array = array(
                array(1,'Benz'),
                array(3,'Toyota'), 
                array(4,'Mazda'),
                [2,'VW'],
                [5,'Mazda']
            );


$count = array_count_values(array_column($array, 1));

print_r($count);
```

Which will output (with `Mazda=>2` as expected)

```
Array
(
    [Benz] => 1
    [Toyota] => 1
    [Mazda] => 2
    [VW] => 1
)
```